# Перебрать все из словаря в сообщении

Tags: python

Есть словарь в котором есть номера телефонов и их баланс

```
{'78888888888': 1.83, '79999999999': 64.0, '76666666666': 0.0, '74444444444': 380.28, '755555555555': 3040.85}
```

Сейчас реализовано так что на каждый номер телефона отправляется отдельное сообщение
[image]

Как сделать что бы все номера были в одном сообщении?

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot("")
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def text(message):
    NumberBalance = {'78888888888': 1.83, '79999999999': 64.0, '76666666666': 0.0, '74444444444': 380.28, '755555555555': 3040.85}
    for login, balanceNum in NumberBalance.items():
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"+{login}  | {balanceNum}₽")


bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```py
NumberBalance = {'78888888888': 1.83, '79999999999': 64.0, '76666666666': 0.0, '74444444444': 380.28, '755555555555': 3040.85}
message = '\n'.join(f"+{login}  | {balanceNum}₽" for login, balanceNum in NumberBalance.items())
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message)
```